# Python can only join an iterable

Tags: python, discord, youtube, discord.py

So basically I'm making a discord bot that plays music, I am trying to make it so that if the user types a keyword the bot will search it and play the music

this is the code im using:

```
@commands.command()
  async def search(self, arg):
    try:
      requests.get("".join(arg))
    except: arg = " ".join(arg)
    else: arg = "".join(arg)
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{arg}", download=False)['entries'][0]
      return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}
```

but python gives me this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command search:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Musik/music.py", line 41, in search
    arg.reverse()
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'reverse'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Musik/music.py", line 43, in search
    except: arg = " ".join(arg)
TypeError: can only join an iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

Comment: well...what is `arg`? Since you are calling `join()` with it you must think it's a collection of things. Python is telling you it's not. Did you mean to use `*args`?